# Simulating the passage of time with testrpc

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Any tips on how to simulate real network conditions on the testrpc testing client using truffle?  I have some functions that look at blocknumber and try to deal with passing time.  Has anyone come up with a good way to test these kind of things?

I'm wondering if just calling some null transactions in a loop with increase the block number accordingly.  Any info on the inner workings of these things would be appreciated.

Comment: For simulating time in tests, here's a tool written by Chris Hitchcott: [https://github.com/DigixGlobal/tempo](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/tempo)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, every transaction called in testrpc is immediately mined and the block height will increase. The time it takes to mine each block can be set as a [command line option](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc#usage) when starting testrpc using `-b` or `--blocktime`

In addition, testrpc provides a [custom rpc method](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc#implemented-methods) you can use to manipulate the block height:

> `evm_mine` : Force a block to be mined. Takes no parameters. Mines a block independent of whether or not mining is started or stopped.

Testrpc's custom methods can be called from web3 using `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync()` like so:

```
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  method: "evm_mine",
  id: 12345
}, function(err, result) {
  // this is your callback
});
```

Comment: I'd love some clarification in this answer! e.g. How can I make testrpc pass 180 days?

Comment: @mesqueeb There's a method in ganache called [evm_increaseTime](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core)

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to write time precise test by using own wrapper:

```js
const { time } = require('openzeppelin-test-helpers');    

async function timeIncreaseTo (seconds) {
    const delay = 1000 - new Date().getMilliseconds();
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
    await time.increaseTo(seconds);
}
```

I noticed that Ganache-cli switches EVM seconds exactly when host switches seconds. So I added waiting for new second and then increase time on EVM. So, I have 1 exact second to perform all necessary transactions and calls until EVM time will be switched.

Usage:

```js
const { time } = require('openzeppelin-test-helpers');    

// Skip 10 sec to have exact 1 second
await timeIncreaseTo((await time.latest()).addn(10));

await this.contract.deposit(1000000);
const timeDeposited = await time.latest();

// Skip 1 year
await timeIncreaseTo(timeDeposited.add(time.duration.years(1)).subn(1));

expect(await this.contract.balanceOf(wallet)).to.be.bignumber.equal('1060000'); // +6%
await this.contract.withdrawAll();
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked consistently for me. Everything else had issues with sometimes being off by 1 second (depending how long my test took to execute)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an entire article about this: [Writing Accurate Time-Dependent Truffle Tests](https://medium.com/sablier/writing-accurate-time-dependent-truffle-tests-8febc827acb5).

**TLDR;**

While I strongly advise to check it out (there's some subtleties involved), here's the short story.

Either do `npm install ganache-time-traveler` or copy-paste the following in your project:

```
const advanceBlockAtTime = (time) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    web3.currentProvider.send(
      {
        jsonrpc: "2.0",
        method: "evm_mine",
        params: [time],
        id: new Date().getTime(),
      },
      (err, _) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        const newBlockHash = web3.eth.getBlock("latest").hash;

        return resolve(newBlockHash);
      },
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: Interesting read, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

1. 1.`evm_increaseTime`: increases the time for the next block.
2. 2.`evm_mine`: mines a new block.

You don't even need a Tardis or a DeLorean for this kind of time travel.

Let me explain how these functions work:

Every time a new block gets mined, the miner adds a timestamp to it. Let's say the transactions that created our zombies got mined in block 5.

Next, we call `evm_increaseTime` but, since the blockchain is immutable, there is no way of modifying an existing block. So, when the contract checks the time, it will not be increased.

If we run `evm_mine`, block number 6 gets mined (and timestamped) which means that, when we put the zombies to fight, the smart contract will "see" that a day has passed.

Putting it together, we can fix our test by traveling through time as follows:

```
await web3.currentProvider.sendAsync({
  jsonrpc: "2.0",
  method: "evm_increaseTime",
  params: [86400],  // there are 86400 seconds in a day
  id: new Date().getTime()
}, () => { });

web3.currentProvider.send({
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    method: 'evm_mine',
    params: [],
    id: new Date().getTime()
});
```