# Time-dependent tests with Hardhat?

Tags: ganache, testing, time, hardhat

For Ganache, there are several [solutions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15755/simulating-the-passage-of-time-with-testrpc/73698#73698).

What about Hardhat? They implemented their own local blockchain, Hardhat Network, which is different to Ganache.

Comment: The buidlerevm page says it supports ganache's `evm_increaseTime` and additionally they have `evm_setNextBlockTimestamp`.

Comment: @Ismael your comment is a legitimate answer. Feel free to post it :)

Comment: I can't test right now, but I'll add an answer when I've more time.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

## Using Hardhat Network Helpers

The easiest way to do this is to use the time helpers in [Hardhat Network Helpers](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/overview).

Install them with:

```
npm install @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers
```

And then you can use them like this:

```ts
import { time } from "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers";

async function main() {
  // advance time by one hour and mine a new block
  await helpers.time.increase(3600);

  // mine a new block with timestamp `newTimestamp`
  await helpers.time.increaseTo(newTimestamp);

  // set the timestamp of the next block but don't mine a new block
  await helpers.time.setNextBlockTimestamp(newTimestamp);
}

main();
```

You can check the reference [here](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference#time-helpers).

## Using raw JSON-RPC calls

There are two relevant RPC methods here: `evm_increaseTime` and `evm_setNextBlockTimestamp`. In both cases, they affect the next block but don't mine one.

`evm_increaseTime` receives a number of seconds that will be added to the timestamp of the latest block. `evm_setNextBlockTimestamp` receives an absolute UNIX timestamp (again, in seconds), and so it's not affected by the current block.

### Examples

#### evm_increaseTime

```js
// suppose the current block has a timestamp of 01:00 PM
await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [3600])
await network.provider.send("evm_mine") // this one will have 02:00 PM as its timestamp
```

#### evm_setNextBlockTimestamp

```js
await network.provider.send("evm_setNextBlockTimestamp", [1625097600])
await network.provider.send("evm_mine") // this one will have 2021-07-01 12:00 AM as its timestamp, no matter what the previous block has
```

Keep in mind that Hardhat Network validates that the new timestamp is bigger than the previous one, so you can't send *any* value.

Comment: When using this with hardhat I got this issue: Error: Transaction reverted and Hardhat couldn't infer the reason. Please report this to help us improve Hardhat.

Comment: Did anyone face the same issue ?

Comment: @Franco this way also works: await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [timestampInSeconds]);

Comment: What's the difference between using `ethers.provider` rather than `network.provider`? I used both and they both seem to work.

Comment: For low-level JSON-RPC calls like these, they are the same. `network.provider` is "just" an EIP-1193 provider object. `ethers.provider` also implements that interface, but it has more functionality. I wrote about that at length here if you're interested: https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/hardhat-networks-and-providers

Answer (score 11):

A [new update](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli-archive/commit/6c0d5820bc3634fa00cbeb2bd97ad721066761a5) to Ganache has added a time parameter to the `evm_mine` command. Now the best way to move time is

```js
await ethers.provider.send("evm_mine", [newTimestampInSeconds]);
```

It is better because you only make 1 RPC call instead of 2 in the [accepted solution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/92906).

Note that you can't move time backwards in Hardhat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this question was about Hardhat, not Ganache.

Comment: My answer was written for hardhat in mind, I linked to the ganache update since hardhat docs for `evm_mine` just say `same as ganache` which lead me to believe hardhat reuses some parts of ganache-cli.

I am using the solution in my tests with hardhat, and they work perfectly :)

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#special-testing-debugging-methods

Comment: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/pull/13/files

Found the ticket from the active ganache repo

Answer (score 8):

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

const sevenDays = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

const blockNumBefore = await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber();
const blockBefore = await ethers.provider.getBlock(blockNumBefore);
const timestampBefore = blockBefore.timestamp;

await ethers.provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [sevenDays]);
await ethers.provider.send('evm_mine');

const blockNumAfter = await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber();
const blockAfter = await ethers.provider.getBlock(blockNumAfter);
const timestampAfter = blockAfter.timestamp;

expect(blockNumAfter).to.be.equal(blockNumBefore + 1);
expect(timestampAfter).to.be.equal(timestampBefore + sevenDays);
```

Comment: this worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

For any future wanderers:

Hardhat added a network-helpers library with convenient JS interface:

- https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/overview
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers

Among other things, there are functions to change network time: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference#time-helpers.

Some examples copied from the reference:

```js
// advance time by one hour and mine a new block
await helpers.time.increase(3600);
// advance time to specific timestamp and mine a new block
await helpers.time.increaseTo(newTimestamp);
// set the timestamp of the next block but don't mine a new block
await helpers.time.setNextBlockTimestamp(newTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

What I've been using with typescript and hardhat:

```
import { ethers, waffle } from 'hardhat';

const time = now + 86400
await ethers.provider.send('evm_setNextBlockTimestamp', [now]); 
await ethers.provider.send('evm_mine');
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in hardhat currently, if I log out the result of the first call, I get the new time I'm trying to set to, but further assertions down the line don't seem to respect that new time. Also, I had to add an empty array after the `evm_mine` argument since its required.Logging out thee result of the `evm_mine` call is 0x0

Comment: Is there a simple way to get `now` instead of `(await ethers.provider.getBlock(await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber())).timestamp`?

Comment: @Martian just use "latest" instead of fetching the last block number. But other than that change, this is about as short as it gets.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to Franco's answer, there is a plugin that abstracts some of the complexities of handling time directly.

You can look its documentation in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@atixlabs/hardhat-time-n-mine

Comment: Returns `404`. Is it moved to some different place? @GonzaloPetraglia

Comment: Fixed the link while this [PR](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/pull/2179) is open

Comment: This is why answers w/ no content and just links are discouraged