# Modify block number when testing with Hardhat

Tags: testing, hardhat

I see that is it is possible to define the timestamp of the next block ([see here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86633/time-dependent-tests-with-hardhat)) in this way:

```js
await network.provider.send("evm_setNextBlockTimestamp", [1625097600]);
await network.provider.send("evm_mine");
```

but what about setting the block number?

My contracts use `block.number` to perform operations and I need to verify that they act correctly by mining a block with a greater height.

Comment: You can use the `evm_mine` method, but if you want to mine multiple blocks you'll need to call it as many times as you need. But this is not practical if you want to advance thousands of blocks. We are going to add a new method that adds support for this.

Comment: @FrancoVictorio is there an update on this?

Comment: You can subscribe to this issue to get notified when this is implemented: https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/issues/1112

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most up to date method is with [hardhat-network-helpers](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/overview)

`yarn add --dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers`

```
const { mine } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");

async function main() {
  // instantly mine 1000 blocks
  await mine(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up modifying the `block.number` by mining multiple blocks as it was suggested in the comment by Franco Victorio.

This is the code:

```js
async function mineNBlocks(n) {
  for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    await ethers.provider.send('evm_mine');
  }
}
```

Then it is called with:

```js
await mineNBlocks(750);
```

It was a bit slow, but it worked quite well for what I needed it.

Answer (score 1):

There's now a Hardhat method exactly for that:

From [hardhat docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference#hardhat_mine):

```
// mine 256 blocks
await hre.network.provider.send("hardhat_mine", ["0x100"]);

// mine 1000 blocks with an interval of 1 minute
await hre.network.provider.send("hardhat_mine", ["0x3e8", "0x3c"]);
```