# Waffle Ethereum tests: advancing N blocks efficiently

Tags: testing, waffle

Title really says it all. I am writing a test for a smart contract that needs to wait 200 blocks before something can happen. Is there any way I can advance forward 200 blocks in order to test the condition?

Answer (score 0):

Took answer from [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98935/modify-block-number-when-testing-with-hardhat) and made it work:

```
async function mineNBlocks(n: number, provider: MockProvider) {
  for (let index = 0; index < n; index++) {
    await provider.send('evm_mine', []);
  }
}
```

Calling it / checking it:

```
await mineNBlocks(100, provider);
console.log(await provider.getBlockNumber());
```