# Openzeppelin test helper with hardhat config and tests

Tags: truffle, openzeppelin, hardhat, test

I'm using hardhat and I added a task to manipulate time in the `hardhat.config.js` file which is working fine.

```js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-truffle5");
const { time } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

task("increaseDays", "Increase days to currentTime")
  .addParam("days", "The number of days").setAction(
    async (taskArguments) => {
      await time.increase(time.duration.days(Number(taskArguments.days)));
      const newTime = await time.latest();
      console.log('New Time is:', newTime.toString(), new Date(newTime.toString() * 1000));
      return newTime.toString();
  });
 ....
 ....
```

The Problem now is that every test script that implements `const { time } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');` fails directly when I try to run `npx hardhat test --network hardhat ./test/script-test.js`

```
      "before all" hook for "should revert on fallback and receiver function":
     Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
      at Object.InvalidResponse (node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\errors.js:43:16)
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:95:32)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpRequestError (node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:379:8)
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:266:37)
      at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:406:9)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
      at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

The test-script

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { time } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');

describe('Test Contract', () => {
  before(async () => {
    const startTime = BigNumber.from((await time.latest()).toString());
  });
  it('should revert on fallback and receiver function..', () => {
      expect(true).to.true;
  });
 });
```

I'm using  "hardhat": "^2.3.0" and "@openzeppelin/test-helpers": "^0.5.11". Any idea what is the problem and how could I solve it?

Comment: What's inside `script-test.js`?

Comment: I thinks it is not important what inside the scripts, I think  it crash because of the import and using it inside the script. I will provide what inside the test scripts tomorrow

Comment: I added the script @scorpion9979

Comment: Potentially related: [Time-dependent tests with Hardhat?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86633/time-dependent-tests-with-hardhat). As far as I know, OpenZeppelin's test helpers are not compatible with Hardhat and Ethers, because each uses a different big number library.

Comment: thanks @PaulRazvanBerg I used the answer from that question to replace the openzeppelin's test helpers from hardhat.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Not The answer but a workaround:

I was not able to find a solution so I got rid of the openzeppelin's test helpers and used the answer  of this question [Time-dependent tests with Hardhat?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86633/time-dependent-tests-with-hardhat) to write my hardhat tasks

```
task('increaseDays', 'Increase days to currentTime')
  .addParam('days', 'The number of days').setAction(
    async (taskArguments) => {
      const blockBefore = await network.provider.send('eth_getBlockByNumber', ['latest', false]);
      console.log('Timestamp before change', blockBefore.timestamp, new Date(blockBefore.timestamp * 1000));
      await network.provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [86400 * Number(taskArguments.days)]);
      await network.provider.send('evm_mine');
      const blockAfter = await network.provider.send('eth_getBlockByNumber', ['latest', false]);
      console.log('Timestamp after change', blockAfter.timestamp, new Date(blockAfter.timestamp * 1000));
      return true;
    });

task('getTime', 'get current time').setAction(
  async () => {
    const lastestBlock = await network.provider.send('eth_getBlockByNumber', ['latest', false]);
    console.log('Current Timestamp is', lastestBlock.timestamp, new Date(lastestBlock.timestamp * 1000));
    return latestTime.toString();
  });
```

to Run it

```
npx hardhat --network ganache getTime

npx hardhat --network ganache increaseDays --days <number-of-days>
```