# Timestamp is lower than or equal to previous block

Tags: erc-721, timestamp, auctions

I have a function where a specific time should be passed to run it.

```
function placeBid(...) {
  require(auction.startedAt <= block.timestamp, "not started yet");
  ...
}
```

say `startedAt` is a unix value of `1648198972` I'm testing with

```
    beforeEach(async function () {
      await ethers.provider.send("evm_setNextBlockTimestamp", [parseInt(auction.startedAt)]);
      await ethers.provider.send("evm_mine");
    });
```

```
      expect(await Auction.connect(user2).placeBid(...))});
```

```
describe("Success", function () {
      it("Should send bid to previous bidder", async function () {
        expect(bidder).to.equal(user2.address);
        block = await ethers.provider.getBlock("latest");
        console.log("current: ", block.timestamp)
      });
      it("....", async function () {
       ...
      });
});
```

This can actually run `placeBid` which seems it passed the require statement, but I get an error related to timestamp!

Truth is, it always passes the first `it` statement, but it throws this timestamp error when it goes to the next `it` statement.

> InvalidInputError: Timestamp 1648198972 is lower than or equal to previous block's timestamp 1648198986

what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's being run correctly? Might wanna make sure that 'parseInt(auction.startedAt)' is valid (maybe you wanted 'parseInt(await auction.startedAt())'?) and print out current timestamp (to make sure that the new one is bigger).

Comment: thanks for the comment, but those are not the problems

Comment: So it's failing at the "evm_setNextBlockTimestamp" line? Your timestamp needs to be larger than the current timestamp, which would explain the error. Simply removing that line setting the timestamp should work then.

Comment: it''s failing at the second `it` statement and that line is needed since i need to move current time to the future time i.e. 2 days later so require statement for `auction.startedAt` can be passed

Comment: The error is basically saying that you are trying to set the time to the past, meaning that auction.startedAt is already in the past.

Comment: the unix value i'm using for startedAt is 1648198972 which is March 25 one month away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/92906/82480) answer -

> Keep in mind that Hardhat Network validates that the new timestamp is bigger than the previous one, so you can't send any value.

It appears that the issue stems from the fact that you're trying to mine a new block in the past (by setting a timestamp before the last block) leading to the given error.

A simple fix could be to modify `startedAt` to a timestamp in the distant future so that this error can be avoided altogether.

Comment: ok but the unix value i'm using for `startedAt` is `1648198972` which is March 25 one month away.

Comment: As per your HH error the the local network has already passed that timestamp (the last block was mined at `1648198986`)

Comment: yeah weird, i don't understand why it even successfully ran `placeBid` and also the first `it` statement, then failing at the second `it` when the block was mined at `1648198986`

Comment: Just noticed that you've used the `beforeEach()` handle. I'd suspect that if there were other tests running before/after this one they'd also call this handle and try to set the block timestamp to `startedAt` which could explain this behavior.

Comment: yeah i'm running other tests after that then what should i do?

Comment: Suggest refactoring tests so that the timestamp is only set in that particular test i.e. move it out of the `beforeEach()` block. Also recommend going through [this](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) to refactor other tests.