# How to advance blocks in a Hardhat test that uses block.timestamp?

Tags: hardhat, testing, blocks, chai, time

I have this code for a Voting smart contract test:

```
it("Should return true if end time is less than the current timestamp", async function () {
  const { votingSmartContract } = await loadFixture(deployVotingSmartContract);
  const now = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000.0);
  await votingSmartContract.initialise(
    [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000], // candidates
    now + 1 // endTime
  );
  expect(await votingSmartContract.checkVotingIsOver()).to.be.true;

});
```

What this does is basically `initialise` the voting so it finishes in 1 sec, so I can then test that `checkVotingIsOver` returns `true`.

Problem is test is failing because I am getting `false` every time. I have `console.log` the `block.timestamp` that I am checking and it looks like I am always getting it to be 1 LESS than the `now` variable.

How can I wait until `block.timestamp` increases so I can pass this test?

Comment: Consider switching to Foundry and warping in time would become 100x easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hardhat helpers for manipulating time and block.number.

[Time-dependent tests with Hardhat?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86633/time-dependent-tests-with-hardhat)